# regex - any number of digits + digit or [a-z]

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expresion that checks if a string starts with a number of digits (at least one), and then immediately ends with a single letter or a digit.

So:

- `29c` is fine
- `29` is fine
- `2425315651252fsaw` fails
- `24241jl.421c` fails
- `c` fails

The regex I have so far is `(^\d+)([a-z]{1}|\d)` which passes the `29`, `20c`, but also passes stuff like `29cdsd`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please let know if `a` and `1` are valid inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [`(^\d+)([a-z]{1}|\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/JntRwX/2) passes `29cdsd`  because it matches 1 or more digits at the start of the string followed with 1 letter or 1 digit, and allows anything right after.

Use

```
^[0-9]+[a-z0-9]?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDfHs9/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - any 1 or more digits
- `[a-z0-9]?`  -  1 or 0 lowercase ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow the string to be a single character a-z?

Comment: @ohaal Yes, these are the requirements. *a string starts with any number of digits, and then immediately ends with a single letter or a digit*. *Any* means *0 or more*.

Comment: Ah, yes, he says "any number of digits", so I guess that means 0 or more. It is me who has misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ohaal Well, we need confirmation from OP. Your `^\d+[a-z]?$` solution might be actually what OP wants in the end if there is a requirement to disallow just one letter strings. I prefer `[0-9]` here because OP did not specify the regex flavor. Not all flavors support `\d`.

Comment: Ugh sry, yes @ohaal is correct - the string cannot start with a character. Edited the question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

This should follow your rules exactly.

`^\d+[a-z]?$`

Answer (score 0):

You could add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the line  and you can omit the `{1}` part:

`^(\d+)([a-z]|\d)$`

In your regex you are matching a minimum of 2 characters .If you don't need the capturing groups, this could also be written as:

`^\d+[a-z\d]$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2QcsX/1)

That would match:

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `[a-z\d]` A character class which matches a-z or a digit
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

if "any number of digits" might be zero `^\d*\w$`

Answer (score -2):

`^` - start of string

`\d*` - any amount of digits, 0 or more

`[a-zA-z]` - a lowercase and uppercase ASCII letters.

`$` - end of string